# How to correct this recursive code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, recursion

I have the recursive function below that is supposed to travel down the tree and display only the root nodes. There are 2 problems with this. 
1. Not all code paths return a value.
2. The DisplayLeafNode function will not be called more than once within the for loop since it is returned after the first call.

```
 @functions
    {
        public static HelperResult DisplayLeafNode(Node node)
        {

            if (node.nodes != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < node.nodes.Count; i++)
                {
                   return @DisplayLeafNode(node.nodes[i]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return DisplayNode(node);
            }
        }
    }
    @helper DisplayNode(Node node)`enter code here`
    {

        <a>
            @node.NodeName
        </a>
    }
```

Can someone help in correcting this?

Comment: Remove the `return` from the recursive call.

Comment: Do you really need to return `HelperResult`? If not, you can make it a `void` method and remove the `return`s.  Otherwise you need to combine the results within the `for` loop into one return value.

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function calls itself, so your code should be:

```
@helper DisplayNode(Node node)
{

    <a>
        @node.NodeName
    </a>
    @if(node.Nodes != null)
        @foreach(Node innernode in node.Nodes)
        {  
            @DisplayNode(innernode)
        }
}
```

And just call `@DisplayNode(root)` in your template (meaning the `DisplayLeafNode` function is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Specifically what are you trying to achieve? What do you want to return? Lets say you want to return Node. I believe a Node would have 2 props (a value and and an other reference to its Node. or may be a list of node).

To reply on what to achieve it would be more useful to know how you have arranged your data structure for Node. 
Based on your ds you can device a cleaner algorithmic approach to check for a node ref and based on its count, to go further down or further up to reach your last node or parent node.

If you have to return a HelperResult and not find a suitable way to do it, then you could better create a new HelperResult. A sure flaw if you are picky about memory consumption, 
but would rather device a cleaner approach on when you want to return and what you want to return.